# Leveldb framework not found swift

Tags: swift, frameworks, leveldb

I recently upgraded my Xcode to the latest version and a big project I was working on had to be updated and fixed. Once the code updated I tried to run the app on simulator and iOS device but I always get the same error and I don't know where it comes from. I know it means the leveldb framework is missing but I don't find it anywhere on the internet. I am using Firebase.

Here's the error I get

```
ld: framework not found leveldb
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I would really appreciate if one of you knew how to fix this! Thanks